# Centering a nav in html5 that's responsive and uses borders

Tags: html, css

I have found lots of ways to center a nav using tricks. Either by setting the line height and the height equal to each other or using vertical-align with display:table. It worked but my border always came at the bottom of the container rather than text.

```css
*{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
header{
    display:block;
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;
}
nav{
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
nav a{
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
    margin-left:25px;
    font-size: 25px;
}

nav a:hover{
    border-bottom: 3px solid #F3008A;
}
}
```

```html
<header>
<nav>
    <a href="#"> Link </a>
    <a href="#"> Link </a>
    <a href="#"> Link </a>
    <a href="#"> Link </a>
</nav>
</header>
```

To clarify the problem, I want to vertically center the text or the "a" tags within the header block. I would like to do this and also be able to put borders on the "a" tag where the border is close to the text.

Comment: So you want to vertically center the `<nav>` within the `<header>`? When you say add border to the bottom of the text, do you mean the anchors? ie. `text-decoration: underline;` on the `<a>`?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, but the code seems to suggest you want to center the `<a>` tags in your nav?

Comment: Yes I just want the text to be in the center of the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the table-cell display vertical-align approach.

```css
* {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
header {
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:blue;
}
nav {
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle
}
nav a {
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
    margin-left:25px;
    font-size: 25px;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
}
nav a:hover {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #F3008A;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <nav> <a href="#"> Link </a>
 <a href="#"> Link </a>
 <a href="#"> Link </a>
 <a href="#"> Link </a>

    </nav>
</header>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wdabedbv/

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `display:inline-block;` and give `line-height`. It will solved your issue.

Check below your updated code:

```css
*{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
header{
    display:block;
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;
}
nav{
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
}
nav a{
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:100px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
    margin-left:25px;
    font-size: 25px;
}

nav a:hover{
    border-bottom: 3px solid #F3008A;
}
}
```

```html
<header>
<nav>
    <a href="#"> Link </a>
    <a href="#"> Link </a>
    <a href="#"> Link </a>
    <a href="#"> Link </a>
</nav>
</header>
```

Comment: This fails for responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `:Before` as i did since your Height of the nav is fixed it wont be a problem.

[Fiddle Link Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n2mm7c54/3/)

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
header {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
nav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
nav a {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin-left: 25px;
  font-size: 25px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
nav a:hover:before {
  background-color: #F3008A;
  postion: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  content: "";
  height: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 4;
  top: 64px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <a href="#"> Link </a>
    <a href="#"> Link </a>
    <a href="#"> Link </a>
    <a href="#"> Link </a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assert that it is best to use flexbox since it is modern and responsive. The following will work nicely in all relatively modern browsers.

```css
nav {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}
nav > div {
    background-color: pink;
    height: 40px;
    
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-contents: center;
    justify-contents: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}
nav > div:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: red;
}
nav > div > a {
    text-align: center;

    -webkit-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
    <nav>
        <div><a href="google.com">hi</a></div>
        <div><a href="google.com">hi2</a></div>
        <div><a href="google.com">hi3</a></div>
    </nav>
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5np6drxb/).

Here is a [helpful guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) with pictures.